# How to make SQL Script like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I've master table like this .

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and output is

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

what can I do to make output like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like following using `GROUP BY` and `UNION ALL`.

```
select  count(*) CT,Mark
from TableName
group by Mark
union all
select Count(*), 'A+B' as mark
from TableName
where mark in('A','B')
UNION ALL
select Count(*), 'A+C' as mark
from TableName
where mark in('A','C')
union all
select Count(*), 'B+C' as mark
from TableName
where mark in('B','C')
UNION ALL
select Count(*), 'A+B+C' as mark
from TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

do `cross join` and `union all`

```
select mark,count(*) as cnt 
from cte group by mark
union all
 select concat(a.mark,'+',b.mark) as mark,a.cnt+b.cnt as cnt from
(select mark,count(*) as cnt 
from cte group by mark
) a cross join
(
select mark,count(*) as cnt 
from cte group by mark
) b where a.mark<b.mark
union all

select 'A+B+C' ,sum(cnt)
from 
(
select mark,count(*) as cnt 
from cte group by mark
) a
```

output

```
 mark   cnt
   A    1
   B    1
   C    2
  A+B   2
  A+C   3
  B+C   3
  A+B+C 4
```

[demo fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4710f44e40a7923dedff6c727f640d45)

Comment: really good, what should I learn about mysql so that I can make syntax like you?

Comment: @nugrahaTeten practice and try to solve various problem that posted in SO btw if it helps mark it as accepted

Comment: @nugrahaTeten does not it solve your problem